# Maven - Properly structuring modules of different languages in inteliJ

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I've been learning about multi-module projects recently, and i pretty much refactored all my java projects into projects containing multiple small modules. Everything is ok when its all java, but im working on a project now where i have a React App, some python code, as well as java.

So i have a parent module, and i have my java code separated into some modules, but what should i do about the java script and the python? I put the java script in its own module, it has a pom ( with no dependencies to anything), but what does puting this react code in its own module actually do? Maven handles dependencies for my java modules, but here dependencies are handled in a different way, so i cant put any dependency management into the react module pom. Its the same for the python module.

- Why should i even separate anything other than java into its own modules? I've been using modules mainly for optimizing dependency management for third party libraries. Are there benefits for creating modules for the react code and the python code?

Comment: You can safely remove all your mentions of Intellij. Your question is a Maven one, and the fact that you're using IntelliJ won't change the answer.

Comment: @DavidS thanks for the comment. Don't really know why i mentioned inteliJ. Was hoping there were maybe some intelij configurations you could do on the modules or something.

Comment: The multi-module idea applies only to java maven/gradle based projects. You can put other projects in sub-directories with java project but reactjs and python projects are not pom based.

Comment: @MithunS So is there any point in putting them in modules as oppose to just normal directory folders? I can see that in intelij when creating a new module you have an option to set that module as a python module or a react module, but what is the point of that ?

Comment: I hope you are not confusing IntelliJ modules with java or maven's multi-module reactor project concept.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Comment: @MithunS i definitely was. So i can use inteliJ modules to keep the code separated and keep framework specific settings and stuff and such. Can i declare dependencies between these inteliJ modules or is that a maven module feature only?

Comment: I still dont fully understand how your inter-language modules are dependent on each other. You can specify how to build them in a guaranteed order which is somewhat required because most projects , people will put java project to run on a different port than reactjs project because one is logically backend and other is front-end.
Are you trying to do something different from what I just mentioned ? 
Are you trying to consume the compiled library from one module into another module ?

Comment: @MithunS I am trying to do something like what you mentioned. I have a java back-end, a java script front-end, and another python back-end. Currently i start all of them manually and separately( from command line). Can InteliJ modules help me do something like: When i click run, i want the react server to start, i want the java spring back-end to start, and i want the python flask server to start. And if this is possible, this would be because of the InteliJ modules and because of Inteliji itself right? It would have no relation to maven modules?

Comment: Have you tried looking into using docker-compose for this ?

Comment: I only know that Docker exists, i dont really know anything about it, but i can definitly look into it. Thank you for the help. The distinction between intelij modules and maven modules really helped me, feel free to put that in an answer and i will accept it!

Comment: Emperor you might find [this blog post](https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e) helpful. It doesn't exactly answer your questions, but it should give you something to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is an idea.
lets say you have these folders/directories, each of them represents a different project.

```
MyAwesomeProject
->db
->rest-api-java-maven
->reactjs-ui
->python-web-app
->scripts
  ->front-end.ps1
  ->back-end.ps1
  ->db.ps1
  ->back-end-2.ps1
->setup.bat
->docker-compose.yml
```

Make your setup.bat run scripts from scripts folder.

```
#Contents of setup.bat file

@echo off
start PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "scripts\front-end.ps1"
start PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "scripts\db.ps1"
start PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "scripts\back-end.ps1"
exit
```

And those individual script file will start each individual docker container
for instance,

```
#Contents of db.ps1
cd db
$containerID = docker ps -q
docker kill $containerID
docker build . --tag=db
docker run -p 27017:27017 db

#Contents of back-end.ps1
cd rest-api
.\mvnw clean install -DskipTests=true
.\mvnw spring-boot:run

#Contents of ui.ps1
cd ui
npm run start
```

And then have each of those projects(and I say projects not modules, because java back-end project can have multiple modules)
 have their own Dockerfile

Now all you need to do is run the bat file and your project will be initialized correctly.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad answer, it's a very modern one, but it does a lot of complexity to bring Docker into the picture. I feel like it would be Emperor to learn "the old fashioned way" first, though I admit I don't know exactly what that is.

Comment: I think the old fashioned way would be to not use docker or docker-compose at all, and let your scripts setup each process and on a different port. I think that could also work.